# showing exception on insertion data in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a form on which controls are assigned
[image]

and this is the code when i clicked insert button

```
private void btnInsertRArtist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand("InsertRecordingArtists", conect);
        comand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        try
        {
            if (txtboxRArtistName.Text == string.Empty || txtboxPlaceOB.Text == "")
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(txtboxRArtistName, "Enter the Music category");
            }
            else
            {
                conect.Open();
                comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordingArtistName", txtboxRArtistName.Text);
                comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", dateTimePicker1);
                comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthPlace", txtboxPlaceOB.Text);
                SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(comand);
                comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                txtboxRArtistName.Text = "";
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            conect.Close();
        }
    }
```

but when i inserted data then this exception comes

[image]

what can i do here...my store procedure is also here

```
ALTER PROCEDURE InsertRecordingArtists
 @RecordingArtistName text,
 @DateOfBirth datetime,
 @BirthPlace text
```

AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [MusicCollection].[dbo].[RecordingArtists]
           ([RecordingArtistName],[DateOfBirth],[BirthPlace])
     VALUES
           (@RecordingArtistName,@DateOfBirth,@BirthPlace)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `DateTimePicker` instance as a query parameter. Use `DateTimePicker.Value` instead:

```
comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", dateTimePicker1.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your

```
comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", dateTimePicker1);
```

to

```
comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", dateTimePicker1.Text);
```

What you do is you can't add a `DateTimePicker` instance as a parameter. `AddWithValue` method takes string as a second parameter. Use [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) or [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt6y6733.aspx) properties.

Answer (score 0):

dateTimePicker1 is a control not a DateTime value.
U need to get the DateTime value from:

```
comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the value of `dateTimePicker1`, you should change:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", dateTimePicker1);
```

to

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", dateTimePicker1.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

What Dennis said is correct. Additionally you probably want to show an error message if it doesnt work.

eg:

```
private void btnInsertRArtist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand("InsertRecordingArtists", conect);
        comand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        try
        {
            if (txtboxRArtistName.Text == string.Empty || txtboxPlaceOB.Text == "")
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(txtboxRArtistName, "Enter the Music category");
            }
            else
            {
                conect.Open();
                comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordingArtistName", txtboxRArtistName.Text);
                comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", dateTimePicker1.Value);
                comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthPlace", txtboxPlaceOB.Text);
                SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(comand);
                comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                txtboxRArtistName.Text = "";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {  
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conect.Close();
        }
    }
```